# i have a doubly linked list kind of data structure in my project, how can i store it in coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a doubly-LinkedList kind of data structure in my project:

for simplicity assume it is: like doubly LinkedList where data is some Random Id (Integer). Again the purpose of this question is not where should I use doubly LinkedList and where should I not. the purpose is how to store them in core data.

how can we store doubly LinkedList it in core data?

Comment: Core Data is for storing managed objects.  If you can define your data and relationships in a managed object model, you can store it.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: If you must persist the order of the linked list then I think it is better to add some sort attribute to the data entity instead of trying to store the structure of the linked list. That way you can easily restore the same order the elements in the list (or any other collection type that supports sorting)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply have a table (`ManagedObject`) called `ListItem` with properties for `previousItem` and `nextItem`. The fist item's `previousItem` and the last's `nextItem` would be `nil`. You can also have another table called `DoubleLinkedList` or someting like it, which is referenced from `ListItem`.